# Prove or disprove: $\forall A,B \Big(A=B-(B-A)\Big)$ where $A,B$ are sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We can write $$B-(B-A)=\{x:x\in B \wedge x\notin B-A\}=\{x:x\in B \wedge (x\notin B \vee x\in A)\}=\{x:F \vee (x\in B \wedge x\in A)\}$$ or $B-(B-A)=\{x:F\vee (x\in B \wedge x\in A)\}$ where $F$ is  a false statement.

Notice that for $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$, $B-(B-A)=\emptyset$ which tells us that $A=\{a\} \wedge B=\emptyset $ is a counterexample.

I'm a newbie so I dunno whether my answer is wrong.

Comment: Let $A = \{1, 2\}, B = \{2\}$ then $B-A = \{\}$ and $B-(B-A) = \{2\} \neq A$ so the statement is false.

Comment: You can prove $$B-(B-A)=A\cap B$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is my answer wrong?

Comment: $\{x: F \vee (x \in B \wedge x \in A)\} = \{x : x \in B \wedge x \in A\} = B \cap A$. Also it can be shown easily using Venn diagram.

Comment: Your counterexample is okay. I would note $F\lor p$ is usually shortened to just $p.$ Then you get my result, $B-(B-A)=B\cap A.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Haven't picked up on that. I truthfully thank you!

Comment: When providing a counterexample, you don’t need all the reasoning before. (Which was why I missed the counterexample, because I thought you were trying to prove the result.)

Comment: It’s also unclear why you start with the example, $A=\emptyset, B=\emptyset.$ It doesn’t add to your counterexample, just confuses it. You imply your real counterexample somehow follows from it, but it doesn’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample is fine.

When presenting a counterexample, just present it. You don’t need any reasoning beyond:

> $A=\{a\},B=\emptyset$ means $B-A=\emptyset$ and $$B-(B-A)=\emptyset\neq A.$$

That’s all you need to say. The rest of your answer - most of it - hides your counterexample.

Your imply that $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ somehow relates to your counterexample. But you don’t really care about the case $A=\emptyset.$ In fact, when $A=\emptyset,$ $A=B-(B-A)$ is true.

Answer (score 2):

If $B = \varnothing$,$B - A = \varnothing$, thus your left hand side is $\varnothing$, whatever $A$ may be.

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the RHS as:
\begin{align*}
B - (B - A) & = B\cap(B\cap A^{c})^{c}\\\\
& = B\cap(B^{c}\cup A)\\\\
& = (B\cap B^{c})\cup(B\cap A)\\\\
& = \varnothing\cup(B\cap A)\\\\
& = B\cap A
\end{align*}

Consequently, $B - (B - A) = A$ iff $B\supseteq A$.

Hopefully this helps!